# A general formulation from which DeMorgan’s formulas follow

Tags: elementary-set-theory

According to my book, the formulas $X-(\bigcup U_\alpha)= \bigcap (X-U_\alpha)$, $X-\bigcap U_\alpha= \bigcup (X-U_\alpha)$ are nonsymmetric cases of a single formulation, which contains, in a symmetric way, sets and their complements, unions, and intersections. I couldn’t find any such formulation, how can I find one?

Comment: There is nothing symmetric about it.  The two statements are duals of each other.  Replace U with its complement and take the complement of both sides.

Comment: @WilliamElliot according to my book there is a single formulation containing both of De Morgan’s laws as specific cases

Comment: Yes, those dual equations are basically the same as I showed.  Your turn to show us this single formulation thing.

Comment: Yes they are basically the same, but what the problem wants is something else @WilliamElliot

Comment: What book are you reading?  If it does not tell you then I'd dismiss the claim as fantasy or some grotesque thing  like putting a = b and x = y into one equation - $(a - b)^2 + (x - y)^2 = 0.$